# how to make a income statement div with three elements stand in vertical position once the medium width is reached?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm making income statement div with three elements and I would like to have a responsive layout so that these elements change from a horizontal layout to a vertical layout as soon as there is not enough space (particularly from the medium width down)

the default layout should be like this:

+10,000 Supported Companies     +14 Countries Served         +250 Million
Managed

And once the medium width of a device is reached, I want the layout to change to this:

+10,000 Supported Companies

.
+14 Countries Served

.                                      +250 Million Managed

Note: that I want to avoid intermediate states like:
+10,000 Supported Companies  +14 Countries Served
+250 Million Managed

I have tried to achieve the desired behaviour with the settings below, but I could not;

What could I do to achieve the behavior I want?

I'd appreciate any support. Thanks

```css
#results-1 {
  width: 100%;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: -10px -10px 0.7rem 1.8rem;
}

#results-2 {
  gap: 3.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 29px;
  padding-right: -20px;
  text-decoration: underline 5px;
}
```

```html
<div className=' d-flex flex-column' id='results-1'>
  <div className=" d-flex justify-center" id="results-2">
    <span id="emp" className='col-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4'> +10,000 Supported Companies </span>
    <span id='paiat' className='col-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4'>+14 Countries Served </span>
    <span id='money' className='col-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4'>+250 Million Managed </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that below `826px` it's when the elements are breaking, so from there we have to set inside the `media` query the `display: block` to the elements, by which they (the `span`s) get into new line.
The updated code after visiting the demo site is as follows:

```css
#results-1 {
  width: 100%;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: -10px -10px 0.7rem 1.8rem;
}

#results-2 {
  gap: 3.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 29px;
  padding-right: -20px;
  text-decoration: underline 5px;
}


/*responsive code from here*/

@media (max-width:1148px) {
  #results-1 {
    margin-left: auto !important; /*forced because there an important here*/
  }
  #results-2 {
    display: block !important; /*forced for the same reason*/
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  div#results-2 span {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0; /* the gap between the lines*/
  }
}

@media (max-width:383px) {
  div#results-2 span {
    font-size: 6vw !important; /*responsive font size*/
  }
}
```

```html
<div className=' d-flex flex-column' id='results-1'>
  <div className=" d-flex justify-center" id="results-2">
    <span id="emp" className='col-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4'> +10,000 Supported Companies </span>
    <span id='paiat' className='col-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4'>+14 Countries Served </span>
    <span id='money' className='col-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4'>+250 Million Managed </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello @iorgv, I'm sorry for the delay in answering you, I was busy yesterday, thank you very much for your effort in helping me, but even with your answer the elements are still not staying in the vertical position, in fact they are just compressing themselves (if adjusting the screen but not staying vertical) and when it arrives on the small-device they expand completely leaving the 3rd element and more than half of the contents of the 2nd element off the screen, would you like me to show my entire code and share the link github project so you understand what's going on?

Comment: Hello, no problem. Sure, show me the github project link!

Comment: As you said and can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Gs0A.png), they do brake on smaller screen due to the font-size remaining as is. We can shrink the font-size as well, it might be hard to read at first, but that doesn't prevent anybody from zooming in. So, if that's what you'd like we can write a responsive code for that as well. Nothing special, we can use the reference of the browser's inspector real time for each breaking point.

Comment: Hello iorgv, here is the link to the codes on github: https://github.com/gabriel9597/PalaceofTriumph14 (the codes are inside the src/inicio Components/inicio folder)

and the project link to test the current responsiveness is this: https://l7g7tm.csb.app/

And of course, maybe reducing the font is a factor that helps, and with the project link above we can test the browser reference for each breakpoint;

Comment: But I would like the elements to be in the center of the screen in a vertical position and with top and bottom spacing between them (for better visibility)
when they reached medium width downwards.

Is this possible with breakpoints?

Comment: Hello! Sure..., please take a look at my answer, I've updated it with new code.

Comment: hello, @iorgv this section worked, it's responsive, thank you very much for your effort in helping me, I'm very grateful for that!

Comment: One more thing, if it doesn't bother you, could you give me some tips on: (courses, articles, things like that) so that I can improve in terms of responsiveness and that I'm a beginner in this subject and would like to improve in this area, but if not Ok, I'm grateful for your help!

Comment: Hello, you're very welcome. Thank you for accepting my answer. I recommend https://www.w3schools.com/ It's site I many times visit; they have really good learning materials and such. You should also get accustomed to look into a site's inspector, you can learn much from there, too.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the tip and help, have a good day!

Comment: You're welcome. Have a good day, too!